# audio playing in "apk" and not playing in "aab"

Tags: java, android

My problem is in playing the sound, as I pack the application in the form of Apk and install it, so the sound works normally without any problems, but when I pack it in the form of aab and upload it to the Google Store and download it from the store, most of the sounds do not work and some of them work, knowing that the audio files are inside the application and they are  Too many and in amr format

android.content.res.Resources$N
otFoundException: File res/raw/
s003001.amr from resource ID
#0x7f0a0126

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening due to the files being compressed while being stored in AAB.

Try adding:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "amr"
}
```

inside module-level `build.gradle` file inside `android { }` block.

Details of [aaptOptions are here](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/AaptOptions).